# Enable Vim mode in gist Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, gist

I'm trying to enable the Ace's keyBoard handler for my beloved Vim on github gists. This seems like it would be an easy thing to do, but I am struggling to:

1. Find the object that the gist ace editor is attached to (the ace default `editor` is not defined)
2. Set it to use VIM, via github's hosted Vim binding: `https://gist.github.com/assets/ace/keybinding/vim-b9f3b98dd13151f9b4c7279d8259b69e.js`

I found the following snippet on the Ace Google Group:

`env.editor.setKeyboardHandler(require("ace/keyboard/keybinding/vim").Vim)`

But that doesn't work (even if I substitute the github url) so i'm assuming that that applies to the Cloud9 IDE, and not selfhosted/custom Ace.

Comment: +1 ... I'm looking for this as well.

Comment: Got some help from the Ace google group. Feel free to try out the code below to see if it works for you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I [posted](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ace-discuss/MItU-g3Qxjc) on the ace Google Group (+rep to Harutyun) and received a reply with the following code:

```
ace.require("ace/lib/net").loadScript("https://rawgithub.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/master/src-min-noconflict/keybinding-vim.js", 
function() { 
    e = document.querySelector(".ace_editor.ace-github").env.editor; 
    e.setKeyboardHandler(ace.require("ace/keyboard/vim").handler); 
})
```

Which works like a charm (Do note that the version of ace that github uses may change, which may break this).

It's a pain to enter this into the console each time, so I plan on adding it to a greasemonkey script (a chrome plugin might be nice! -- well see).

**Update**

---

I've written a small [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pocket-vim/pjnhffdkdckcagdmfmidafhppbomjdjg) that enables Vim bindings on most sites Ace.js and CodeMirror. Issues and contributions welcome at the [github repo](https://github.com/NickTomlin/pocketvim)

Comment: thanks nick! on gists this works for me... but NB it fails on github.com proper.

Answer (score 27):

In the latest version of ace (v1.1.1), vim and emacs bindings come built in. The following works:

```
editor.setKeyboardHandler("ace/keyboard/vim");
```

Comment: +1 thanks for updating. Gists still use the old version of Ace (as of december 2013), but works great for sites using the newer version.

Comment: NOTE: This works, but Ace now supports multiple editors in a page, therefore you won't find the global object for a singular `editor`

Do: `editors[0].setKeyboardHandler("ace/keyboard/vim");`

Comment: It appears that, to revert to the default mode, this works: `editor.setKeyboardHandler("");`

Comment: ** NOTE VIM AND EMACS THAT COMES BUILT IN WITH ACE IS NOT A COMPILER JUST A KEYBINDING **

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get the other two solutions to work.  (Nick's Chrome extension still works perfectly for me, though.)

Another solution is to change to `vim` mode in the settings menu.

To access the settings menu, make sure the ACE editor has focus, and push `ctrl`+`,` (Control and Comma).

This will open the menu on the right hand side of the screen.  Find the "Keyboard Handler" dropdown and select `vim`.  Push `escape` or click somewhere off of the settings menu to close it.

`vim` mode should now be activated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the ace-builds along with react-ace to access themes, keybinding and others

```
npm install react-ace ace-builds
```

In react you have to add the following lines:

```
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/keybinding-vim"
<AceEditor
  ...
  keyboardHandler='vim'
  ...
/>
```